# Corda Accounts implementation using java failed while creating accounts due to dependencies error

Tags: java, spring, gradle, corda

We are trying to create accounts using java and to create accounts we need to use the "accountservice" library (com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.accountService => kotlin) but in java we are not able to get it in a same way (com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.services.AccountService => java).So What we have did is we have imported the above library in java code and tried to inject using autowired annotation but it is giving below error as:Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/home/lti-blockchain/Desktop/teju/corda_practice/corda_accounts/Corda-accounts/workflows/src/main/java/com/lti/blockchain/corda/flows/CreateAccountFlow.java:7: error: package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
^
/home/lti-blockchain/Desktop/teju/corda_practice/corda_accounts/Corda-accounts/workflows/src/main/java/com/lti/blockchain/corda/flows/CreateAccountFlow.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
@Autowired
^
symbol: class Autowired
location: class CreateAccountFlow
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
:workflows:compileJava (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.196 secs.FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':workflows:compileJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your question is malformatted and it's very hard to read; please next time use markdown styling (specifically the 3 backticks to surround code blocks: https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks).
2. `AccountService` is an interface not a class, so you cannot use it; you need to use its implementing class `KeyManagementBackedAccountService`.
3. To get the service, use this inside your flow:

```
getServiceHub().cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService.class);
```

4. You don't need the service to create accounts, the service is just a utility to make things easier. If you open it, you'll see that it calls flows that you can use yourself:

```java
// As you can see, this service method calls "CreateAccount()" flow.
@Suspendable
override fun createAccount(name: String): CordaFuture<StateAndRef<AccountInfo>> {
    return flowAwareStartFlow(CreateAccount(name))
}
// So inside your flow you can do this instead of calling the service method:
subFlow(new CreateAccount("some username"));
```